# a representation question on AR(P) process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, time-series

For AR(P) process, I once read the following property:

[image]

**P** corresponds to the projection on the space $\bar{sp}\{x_2,...x_k\}$, which is defined as follows

[image]

I do not know how does equation (3.4.1) was derived

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RHS of (3.4.1) belongs to the span, $X_t$ equals the RHS of (3.4.1) plus $Z_t$, and the projection of $Z_t$ on the span is $0$. QED.